# React Native - Add option to context menu in browsers on android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using react native 0.71. I want to add an option to the context menu appear after select some text in the web browser such as Opera, Chrome on android. The option will open the application and pass the selected text to the application as arguments. I noticed some application such as Office Note that can do this. Is there anyway that I can implement this with react native?[image: example]